# How do I use bitwise operations to negate only the upper 4 bits in a pixel?

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

I have to decode an image by negating the upper 4 bits of each pixel. How can I do this using bitwise operations?

Comment: Do you actually mean to negate all the 4 first bits of a byte, per byte?

Answer (score 2):

You can apply bitwise operations on data, not pixels. So the answer to your question depends on how pixels are encoded in your application.

Having said that, to negate (assuming you mean "toggle") the leftmost four bits of a byte you should apply a bitwise XOR with the mask 11110000:

```
b ^= 0b11110000;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming 32-bit ints:

```
x = (~x & 0xFF000000) | (x & 0x00FFFFFF)
```